# process.env.EDGE_APP_ROOT what is?

Tags: javascript, node.js, edgejs

I'm almost done refactoring code taken from here:
https://github.com/agracio/edge-js-quick-start

I've added two classes that handle repeatable code, but I'm stuck in two lines of code. I can't for the life of me figure out what they do. I also don't seem to understand what edge_app_root targets (it's a folder but I suspect it targets some file? )

process.env.EDGE_USE_CORECLR = 1;
process.env.EDGE_APP_ROOT = baseNetAppPath;

```js
const path = require('path');
var version = process.argv[2];

// print process.argv
process.argv.forEach((val, index) =>
{
    console.log(+index + ":" + val);
});
console.log();

//by default the core will be used (and standard  is not supported)
var namespace = 'QuickStart.' + version.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + version.substr(1);
if (version === 'core')
{
    version = 'coreapp';
    console.log("coreapp");
}
const baseNetAppPath = path.join(__dirname, '/src/' + namespace + '/bin/Debug/net' + version + '2.0');

process.env.EDGE_USE_CORECLR = 1;
if (version !== 'standard')
{
    console.log("version is not standard")
    process.env.EDGE_APP_ROOT = baseNetAppPath;
    console.log("process.env.EDGE_APP_ROOT:\n" + baseNetAppPath+"\n");
}

var edge = require('edge-js');

var baseDll = path.join(baseNetAppPath, namespace + '.dll');
console.log(`basedll: ${baseDll}`);

//load functions from namespaces.cs files
var localTypeName = namespace + '.LocalMethods';

var namespace2 = namespace + '.InnerMethods';
console.log(`Using basedll:${baseDll}\n namespace2:${namespace2}\n`);
var getList = edge.func({
    assemblyFile: baseDll,//should be the same
    typeName: namespace2,//namespace + '.InnerMethods',
    methodName: "GetList"
});

getList('', function (error, result)
{
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(namespace + '.InnerMethods');
    console.log(result + "\n");
});
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

From the Edge.js ReadMe:

> If you are using .NET Core and are using the .NET Core SDK and CLI,
> you must have a project.json file (specification here) that specifies
> the dependencies for the application. This list of dependencies must
> also include the Edge.js runtime package and, if you need to be able
> to dynamically compile your code, the package(s) for the compilers
> that you plan to use, like Edge.js.CSharp. You must have run the
> dotnet restore (to restore the dependencies) and dotnet build (to
> build your project and generate the dependency manifest) commands in
> that project's directory to generate a .deps.json file under
> bin/[configuration]/[framework], i.e.
> bin/Release/netstandard1.6/MyProject.deps.json. This .deps.json file
> must either be in the current working directory that node is executed
> in or you must specify its directory by setting the EDGE_APP_ROOT
> environment variable. For example, if for a netstandard1.6 project in
> the c:\DotNet\MyProject directory, you would run something like:
>
> ```
> set EDGE_APP_ROOT=c:\DotNet\MyProject\bin\Release\netstandard1.6
> node app.js
> ```

Source: https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge

By default edge looks for its config files (ex: .deps.json) in your current working directory or you if those files are somewhere else you'd specify the directory with EDGE_APP_ROOT.

Comment: I have fixed the issue by first using "dotnet build" in the power shell. I then proceeded to compare everthing between the original sample code and my refactored code. I found that 
"var edge = require('edge-js');" MUST come after setting the process.env variables.